# Can't add item via Angular 1.x

Tags: html, angularjs

Just started to learn Angular. I try to make a simple shopping list app, but 'Add' button doesn't work.
When I press it (`ng-submit="addItem()"`) nothing happen. Apparently `$scope.addItem` doesn't work correctly.

```js
var myModule = angular.module('list', []);
myModule.controller('ListCtrl', ListCtrl);

function ListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      { text: 'Chocolate', done: true },
      { text: 'Potato', done: false },
      { text: 'Banana', done: false },
      { text: 'Water', done: true }
    ];
 
    $scope.addItem = function () {

        $scope.items.push({ text: $scope.itemText, done: false });
        $scope.itemText = '';
    };

    $scope.remain = function () {
        var count = $scope.items.length;

        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
            count -= item.done;
        });
        return count;
    };
}
```

```css
.list{
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}
.done-false {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="list">
<head>
  <title>Document 1</title>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

 <div class="list">
  <h2>Shopping List</h2>
  <div class="panel" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <span>{{remain()}} item(s) left to buy of {{items.length}}</span>
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td><input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.done"></td>
      <td><span class="done-{{item.done}}">{{item.text}}</span></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>

  <form ng-submit="addItem()">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="itemText" size="30" placeholder="Add item to list">
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/ArkadiyS/pen/BzWjvX

Comment: your form is outside the div of the controller

Comment: @Sam, Oh... Well, definitely I need a rest :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code and make sure your `<form>` should be inside your `<div class="panel" ng-controller="ListCtrl">`.

Comment: that's okay, no worries!